# GSMA OneApi send sms

Tags: php, curl, sms, send

I am trying to use The OneAPI SMS interface to send SMS messages from my application using cURL.

It returns 500 error and here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
$url = "https://oneapi-gw.gsma.com/smssend/2_0/smsmessaging/outbound/tel%3A%2B1234/requests";
$username = "secret";
$password = "secret";

$request = array(
    'address' => 'tel%3A%2B1222333444',
    'message' => 'hello world',
    'senderAddress' => 'tel%3A%2B1234',
    'senderName' => 'joe doe'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($request));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($info);
?>
```

Any help woudl be any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

P.S.

```
Array ( [url] => https://oneapi-gw.gsma.com/smssend/2_0/smsmessaging/outbound/tel%3A%2B1416XXXYYYY/requests
[content_type] => application/json [http_code] => 500 [header_size] => 494 [request_size] => 349
[filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.333515 [namelookup_time] => 0.000335
[connect_time] => 0.054989 [pretransfer_time] => 0.229044 [size_upload] => 97 [size_download] => 172 [speed_download] => 515
[speed_upload] => 290 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => 97 [starttransfer_time] => 0.333474 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) )
```

Solved

For the ancestors: for some reasons cURL is not working, so file_get_contents() is the way to go.

Comment: Can you include the error? Also have you set the username and password to your own values, as well as setting the destination address to a valid value?

Comment: Can you try using the senderAddress 7511? You need to use this short code to do a send in the sandbox environment.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I updated the post. I tried to use 7511 but it didnt help. Obviously I am using my own values. So I checked their manual and it says: 500 – Internal Error 500; the server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting parameter values in JSON you shouldn't URL encode the values. This is necessary if using 'form post's but not for JSON.

Try making the same request using command line curl - you should be able to get the details of the server error accompanying the 500 return code.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I solved this puzzle with cURL. The problem was in its syntax. Heres the working PHP solution for their APIs.

```
   Class SendSMS {

        public $phone_number;

        public function __construct($phone_number) {
            $this->phone_number = $phone_number;
        }

        public function oneAPI() {      
            $url = "https://oneapi-gw.gsma.com/smssend/2_0/smsmessaging/outbound/tel%3A7511/requests"; // END POINT
            $username = 'secret'; // APP's login
            $password = 'secret'; // and psswd

            $request = array(
                'address' => $this->phone_number,
                'message' => 'hello world',
                'senderAddress' => 'tel:7511'
            );

            $request = http_build_query($request);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // hide output
            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

        }

    }

    $hello = new SendSMS('+1XXXXXXXXX'); // WHITE LISTED PHONE

    $hello->oneAPI();
```